# Testing PWM signal

Tags: pwm, simulink

So im kind of new with using PWM.

I have made a simple comperator using Simulink in order to create PWM signal.

[image]

Now, I had like to pass this PWM signal through "something" which I dont know what in order to check if the output will be again this sine wave that I used in order to create the PWM.

Basically I just want to test my self that if create PWM signal and than use it I get the same signal.

How can I test it using simulink?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "something" would typically be a low-pass filter, with enough attenuation of the carrier and not too much attenuation of the signal.